# Error MSB4024: The imported project file ".csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets" could not be loaded

Tags: .net

I have a .NET Core / Angular project and it was work fine. But when I try to run `dotnet ef migration add` command, it failed to build and generates this error.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft.Common.targets(127,3): error MSB4024: The imported project file "D:\BusinessProjects\Repo\badessaSoftware\obj\badessaSoftware.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets" could not be loaded. Unexpected end tag. Line 26, position 6. [D:\stockmanagement.csproj]

Please help me.

Comment: I still have this problem and I still haven't found the solution.

Comment: hi @VagnerWentz , Remove "bin" and "obj" folders. Then rebuild your project.

Comment: @AminRousta Thanks I deleted the "bin" and "obj" and I restored all projects and rebuild all.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was deleting the ***bin*** and ***obj*** folders and then rebuilding the project as per Rousta's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After a time, I get the problem. The problem was because I added **omnisharp.json** file to root of my project with content:

`{ "MSBuild": { "UseLegacySdkResolver": true } }`

to solve the problem with omnisharp.

After I removed this file it worked.